# Amazon AWS AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider initializing error

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to initialize to create a default service configuration by adding the following code snippet in the Application delegate of an iOS 8 Swift app.

As directed on the Amazon tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) I'm using the following lines of code:

```
//AWS Service Config
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-13453454-92d1-234234-234234-3434")

let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration
```

However the code will not compile as xCode says I am "Missing argument for parameter 'identityId' in Call"

First off, this code is directly from Amazon's tutorial and also I do not have an identiyID, just an identitypoolid (which is scrambled in my code).

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the latest version of the iOS SDK. Please make sure you are using the latest version as not all versions support the simplified constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are using the correct initialiser, try -

```
  let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
     AWSRegionType.USEast1,
     accountId: cognitoAccountId,
     identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId,
     unauthRoleArn: cognitoUnauthRoleArn,
     authRoleArn: nil)
  let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
  AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration(defaultServiceConfiguration)
```

Comment: That is one of the ways to initialize the credentialsProvider. There is a newer simplified version which only requires identityPoolId. See Objective C section under getting credentials http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/step1-getting-started.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cognitoIdentityPoolId = "us-east-XXXXXXXX"
```

{

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: Any document related this?